# Laravel Passport /oauth routes work but not /api

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Building an application with Laravel, Passport and Vue. This question does not directly pertain to logging in with oAuth2, but rather consuming the api that's protected by Passport with your own javascript code, as [per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

When accessing the home page and using axios to get `/oauth`, I get a error 401, as expected.

After logging in using the default login provided by laravel (uses `web` auth), I can go back to the home page, and the axios request for `/oauth` works great; for example `/oauth/clients` returns the clients of the logged in user, as expected.

```
mounted() {

    //works as expected: 401 when logged out and response when logged in via /login
    axios.get('/oauth/clients')
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data)
          })

    //Always returns 400 error
    axios.get('/api/user')
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data)
          })

  }
```

However, when I try with axios to get `/api/user`, I get a 400 error, with the message Unauthenticated (regardless if before or after login, same error).

```
//Returns a 400, always
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

If I'm correct, the fact that the `/oauth` routes work proves that the laravel_token, csrf, and any such things are being sent correctly. Therefore, I think that this is a server side issue, especially with the auth:api guard. In the auth config file, I've set it to use Passport, and followed all the docs.

I'm confused as to why I get a 400 error and not a 401 when calling the api, and why it's not authenticating in the first place.

Especially frustrating since [according to this video](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) (11:30 mark), it's pretty much plug 'n' play.

Same behaviour with Postman.

Q: Any solutions to this error?

Full code [on GitHub](https://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr).

Comment: Hi Michal, how did you solve your question ?

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

Comment: Thanks, just double checked, I already added it -I think the fact that `/oauth` routes work shows that and laravel_token is being sent as mentioned in question.

Comment: No. That code was already added before posting the question - it's not (I think) part of the problem.

Comment: did you have this in your html <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
};                       add this in your view

Comment: Yes - both are there. Again, if they were not, the `/oauth` would not work. I don't think this is a front-end issue.